# 7zip update command doesn't work

Tags: node.js, unzip, git-bash, 7zip, spawn

when i want to unzip my file i call this function from the server :

```
var child = spawn(sevenZip, ["x", filename.trim(), "-o" + outputFolder]);
```

it's works well!

now, 
i want to update the zip file and to add (or remove) a file (without unzip and zip again).

i call this function :

```
var child = spawn(sevenZip, ["u", filename.trim(), filePath]);
```

i tried also this command:

```
var child = spawn(sevenZip, ["u", filename.trim(),"-u" + filePath]);
```

from some reason, it is not working at all.

(but when i write this command in git bash it's works sometimes, i think it depends on witch zipper i used for unzip the file before).

some idea guys ???

Comment: "not working" tells us nothing. Please elaborate.

Comment: Nothing happens, I push the button and sent request to the server that does not make any change (the zip file is not updated)

Comment: Did you try reading from the `child.stderr` (and/or possibly `child.stdout`) stream to see if there is an error being printed there?

Comment: there is no errors shown